# MATLAB: Function returns single value instead of vector

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, vector, distance

I tried to create a function in MATLAB, which returns a vector of the distances between neighboring points in a list of points `(x1,y1),...,(xn,yn)`.

That is `["distance (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)", ... ,"distance (xn-1,yn-1) to (xn,yn)","distance (xn,yn) to (x1,y1)"]`.

To do this, my idea was to work with two vectors:
The original one `[(x1,y1),...,(xn,yn)]` and `[(xn,yn),(x1,y1),...,(xn-1,yn-1)]`.

Now I built this function:

```
function erg = distVec(xy1)

n = length(xy1);
xy2 = cat(1,xy1(2:end,:),xy1(1,:));
 % define snd vector
erg = [];
    for j=n
       erg = cat(2,erg,norm((xy1(j,:)-xy2(j,:))));
        % norm(...) equals distance between two neighboring points
    end
end
```

But instead of an vector with the distances, this function returns only the last distance evaluated.

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: MATLAB doesn't allow you to use tuples like that. In your code, what type is `xy1` supposed to have?

Comment: It's a matrix with the x-values in the fst column and the y-values in the snd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears `xy1` is a two-column matrix, in which each point is a row. Then you can obtain the result without loops as follows:

```
result = sqrt(sum((xy1([2:end 1],:) - xy1).^2, 2));
```

That is: cyclically shift one row (`xy1([2:end 1],:)`), subtract original matrix (`- xy1`), square element-wise (`(...).^2`), sum along each row (`sum(... ,2)`), and take square root (`sqrt(...)`).

Comment: You're rigth, thanks for this easy way! I'm working with Matlab only for a week by now, so my programming isn't very elegant yet.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `length(xy1)` returns, of course, the length of the vector, e.g. 7.

You for loop does `for j=n`, thus for `j=7`. It does not return the **last** distance evaluated, it returns **the only** distance evaluated.

Change the for loop to `for j=1:n`

Comment: Oh no, I feel ashamed rigth now! Sometimes the mistakes are so simple, that you just don't see them... Thanks!

Comment: @sabs If it solved your problem consider accepting the answer, but most likely you shoudl also have a look to what Luis says